# How do I install IronPython?

Tags: python, mono

I tried installing Ironpython on ubuntu 12.04 using the guide here:
[IronPython on Mono](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IronPython%20on%20Mono)
But it doesn't seem to work. I have no *Solutions/IronPython.Mono.sln*, so i try to *xbuild Solutions/IronPython.sln* but it doesn't work because of some errors.

Can someone please point to another way of installing IronPython on Ubuntu?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I found a guide here: 
https://datadrivendesign.wordpress.com/2012/08/05/getting-infer-net-and-ironpython-to-work-on-ubuntu-12-04/

It works now. Thanks guys

Comment: @aburnap link only answers are not welcome in this site - could you post a summary of the steps here?

Comment: The instructions are broken for me at the `xbuild Solutions/IronPython.sln /p:Configuration=Release` step, on Ubuntu 14.04. I get 25 warnings and 2 errors. The 2 errors are `socket.cs(1900,63): error CS0117: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionName' does not contain a definition for 'IPv6Only'` and `c#sqlite/pcache1_c.cs(744,25): error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'pGroup'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Ubuntu Software Center to install, or by clicking below.

[image]

Comment: It's not available in Ubuntu 12.04 software center :(  I get the message: "There isn’t a software package called “ironpython” in your current software sources."

Comment: @MikeSpadd make sure yuo enable the universe, multiverse, and partner repositories first, that'll be vial to checking whether it exists in the repos

Comment: @Lord of Time - I have them already enabled. But there's no IronPython :(

Answer (score -1):

Use the command `sudo apt-get install python-all`

Heres a link to some useful information on python.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/python-all

Comment: I did install this package but it dosen't install IronPython, it says: "dependencies on ironpython may be added."